# Get hierarchy from self referencing table taking to much time to result in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, get, hierarchy

I want to get hierarchy from self referencing table in entity framework linq, But by Linq it is to much time to get hierarchy. The time is near about 5 to 10 minutes on local host.

Table is
**Group**

[Group table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ2Sc.png)
I want to map above table in hierarchy

```
public class GroupHierarchy
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentGroupId { get; set; }
        IList<GroupHierarchy> Children { get; set; }
        public int HierarchyDepth { get; set; }
    }
```

Linq query

```
var hierachy = _unitOfWork.GroupRepository.GetAllGroups().Where(g => g.GroupParentId == null);
var groups = Mapper.Map<List<GroupHierarchy>>(hierachy);
```

Can this query is taking to much time(5-10 mins) for 2000 records to get the result, can someone please help me in this

Thanks 
Mahesh

Comment: Max hierarchy level ?

Comment: ```Mapper.Map``` is that Automapper? Creating a tree -even a Tree with depth of 2000- of 2k records shouldn't take more than a few (hundred) miliseconds. Entity framework resolves the children and parent automatically in my database first scenarios.

Comment: Max hierarchy level is 4

Comment: Yes it is Automapper